# How to create a conditional bean in Spring

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, spring-bean

I need to create a `Conditional` Bean in Spring. The use case is as following:

**Class 1**

In this class we are trying to create the `Bean`, which should be created for some clients who have the required permission, and for others it will return `empty()`. Thus the application should boot-up for all the clients without the `BeanCreationException`

```
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
public class SomeBeanConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Optional<SomeBean> someBean() {
        // whoAmI() ? returns IAmClient_1 - for whom this bean should be created
        // whoAmI() ? returns IAmClient_2 - for whom this bean should not be created
        
        final String somePermission = whoAmI();
        
        try {
            return Optional.of(SomeBean.builder()
                    .withPermission(new SomeCredentialsProvider(somePermission))
                    .build());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.error("SomeBean creation exception : ", ex);
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

**Class 2**
Where we are using this Bean in Constructor injection

```
@Bean
public SomeHelper someHelper(Optional<SomeBean> someBean) {
    return new someHelper(someBean);
}
```

But the `someHelper` for client, who have permission are also getting an `Optional.empty()` in constructor.

What I am doing wrong here? Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your method that's creating the bean.  It should not be returning a bean of type `Optional`, it should be returning a bean of type `SomeBean`.  Also, consider rewriting your logic to something more understandable, like dropping the catch block and creating the bean based on the output of `whoAmI()`.

```
@Bean
public SomeBean someBean() {
    // whoAmI() ? returns IAmClient_1 - for whom this bean should be created
    // whoAmI() ? returns IAmClient_2 - for whom this bean should not be created
    
    String somePermission = whoAmI();
    if (somePermission.equals("IAmClient_1") {
       return SomeBean.builder().withPermission(newSomeCredentialsProvider(somePermission)).build());
    } else {
       return null;
    }
}
```

Now, when you autowire the Optional, the optional will contain the bean for `IAmClient_1`, and will be empty for all other cases.

In my opinion, it would be better to always construct `SomeBean` and just modify its behavior based on the value of the permission you're checking, but that's up to you.

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't return `null` from the bean method. But preferably a noop `SomeBean` (again the case for an interface providing a real implementation and a noop implementation).

Comment: @M.Deinum I couldn't agree with you more.  I tried to make this point with the last sentence.